# How to make composite Foreign Key part of composite Primary Key with Spring Boot - JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with the historization of objects in the database.

- the expected behavior of the save JpaRepository method is : **Insert** in the two tables **idt_h** and **abo_h**
- But the current behavior is **Insert** in the **idt_h** table and **update** in the **abo_h** table.

```java
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ABO_H")
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class AboOP {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ABO_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "ABO_STATUT")
    private String statut;

    @Column(name = "ABO_DATE_STATUT")
    private Instant date;

    @Column(name = "ABO_CoDE")
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "IDC_ID", referencedColumnName = "IDC_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "DATE_HISTO", referencedColumnName = "DATE_HISTO")
    })
    private IdtOP idtOP;

    }


    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "IDT_H")
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class IdtOP {

    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id",
                    column = @Column(name = "IDC_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "dateHisto",
                    column = @Column(name = "DATE_HISTO"))
    })
    @EmbeddedId
    private IdGenerique idtId = new IdGenerique();

    //Other fields

    }


    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Embeddable
    public class IdGenerique implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private Instant dateHisto;

    }
```

I think that the class **IdGenerique** which groups the **id** and **dateHisto** is not well invoked for the table **abo_h** ??

thanks in advance

Comment: If you have many B to one A, why not just have a foreign key in TableB ? I don' t get what  you want to achieve with the @JoinColumns ?

Comment: because I use a composite primary key (id A, date_histo) in class A and I need this key in class B, hence the interest in joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the save() method, entityManager checks if the entity is new or not. If yes, the entity will be saved, if not, it'll be merged

If you implement your Entity Class with the inteface Persistable, you can override the method isNew() and make it returns True. In that case the save() method will persist, and not merge, your entity.